# How do I create a network connection with other computers (JAVA)?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, connection

I'm developing a game that can be played with computer or versus other players. The GUI is Swing but irrelevant for the matter. My question is : how do I connect with other players in a network?

I am familiar with terms like client / server, sockets etc, and i can write a basic client/server program, but it can only be run from ONE computer. I don't know how to connect to this network from a computer, say, half way across the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably setting behind a router which hides your local IP address from the rest of the world (look for [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) for more info on this). Basically, the world only sees your YOUR_ROUTER_IP, your router takes care of carrying all IP packets from the outside world to you and vice versa. You will need to change your router settings so that your computer/server gets the router ip address. This way you can access your server application from anywhere in the world by using simple socket operations.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) for network connections, it works very well and has really good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You indicated you know how to use client and server sockets, so I'll just throw out there that you ought to try connecting with "real" ip address instead of localhost (127.0.0.1). Take two machines on your local network, get the IP address of the "server" machine and use that address to connect from the client.

This will work all the way around the world, except for the fact that you are likely behind some Network Address Translation (NAT) firewalls and will likely need to "open" or "forward" the ports you need. If you need more information on NAT, google and serverfault will be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your client and server is located on the same machine, then you can use loopback address(ie 127.0.0.1), in LAN you can do with private ip addresses

```
Private ip address for LAN
```

CLASS A - 10.x.x.x

CLASS B - 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255

CLASS C - 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

you can use this for LAN environment

For connecting someone over the internet, you will need `Public ip addresses`.
Address apart from the private ip in every range are public address.

Now if you have a server which is having a `static ip` then it wont be a problem for the client to access it anywhere from the world over internet.

But if its over a LAN , and accessing the internet from a gateway, then there will be a `NAT`, then you will need to set the `inbound and outbound traffic rules` at the `gateway`, for letting the client access the server.